# How to add Google Analytics Scripts to Uno WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, xaml, uno-platform

I am trying to add a google tag manager script to the Wasm project. To achieve this I have created a new script file `localscript.js` inside `WasmScripts` folder. This is how that file looks like

```
(function () {
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

    var myScript = document.createElement('script');

    myScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-7');

    head.appendChild(myScript);
})();
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-7');
```

And then I embedded this script to `wasm.csproj` file like this

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="WasmCSS\Fonts.css" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="WasmScripts\AppManifest.js" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="WasmScripts\localscript.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

All looks good to me, But when I run this, `localscript.js` loads before `googletagmanager`. How can I solve this issue so that `googletagmanager` comes first and supporting code comes after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap provided](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap#dependency-management) `require.js`:

```js
require(
    ["https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-7"],
    () => {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-7');
    }
);
```

This will make the code in the arrow function execute once the script has been downloaded.